# RSpec: Stub API call that sets global variable

Tags: global-variables, stub, ruby-2.0, rspec3

In my Ruby (not Rails) program, I have created global variables in the top-level module.  These global variables are set as the clients of external services, so my program makes API calls when they are set.  I am trying to figure out how to properly stub these API calls in RSpec.

I would like to test a class inside the top module, that looks more or less like this.  Worker does not directly call the global variables anywhere in the class.

```
module TopModule
  class Worker
  end
end
```

Here is the TopModule:

```
module TopModule
  # (As an aside, the external service is AWS)
  $client = ExternalService::Client.new(ExternalService.config)
end
```

I would like to run the RSpec test of TopModule::Worker so it passes:

```
describe TopModule::Worker do
  it 'shows in various ways that Worker functions'
end
```

However, I get the following error: `Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET http://... with headers {...} (WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError)`

The stack trace points to the line in TopModule where $client is defined.

I'm also told:

```
You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:get, "http://...").
  with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'...', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

I still have the error when I add the stub to my spec/spec_helper RSpec.configure loop.  Here are the relevant parts of the the spec_helper:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'
require 'codeclimate-test-reporter'
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow: 'codeclimate.com')

require 'fileutils'
require 'top_module'
Dir['./spec/support/**/*.rb'].sort.each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_doubled_constant_names = true
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end

def files_directory
  File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/files'
end
```

Where can I put the stub so it will actually handle the ExternalService API call?  I would appreciate your help.

(This code is based on my real code, but not identical)

Answer (score 0):

you can use VCR to stub external api call.

https://github.com/vcr/vcr